# NorthWind Service Category Images

Tags: jquery, sapui5

I'm using Northwind OData service for the my dummy application.
URL: http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories?$format=json

Here, the Picture  of each Category is defined in a text stream format. I would like to know :

1. What is this text stream format called with respect to image?
2. How to convert this text stream to an Icon in SAPUI5 so I can bind it to my Object List Item.

My List and Object List item:

```
<List
                headerText='{i18n>Categories}'
                mode='None'
                items="{oDataModel>/Categories}">
                <items>
                    <ObjectListItem 
                        title="{oDataModel>CategoryName}"
                        icon="{oDataModel>Picture}"
                        description="{oDataModel>Description}">
                    </ObjectListItem>
                </items>
            </List>
```

Comment: Switching back to XML format you can see that it is actually registered as a binary type ( "<d:Picture m:type="Edm.Binary">FRwvAAIAAA...".

Comment: how would I use it as a Image or Icon ?

Comment: what do you currently get when you execute your code?